# displaying maps from normal text editor instead of notebook

Tags: python

I want to create world maps using folium within a text editor (geany), not using notebooks. this piece of code will work but i cant see the output. i.e, the actual  map. How do i get it to display the map.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[40.0150, -105.2705])

# Display the map
m
```

Comment: You could use `m.save('map.html')` and open this html page in your browser to see the maps content

Comment: That worked! thanks a lot! But what if i dont want to save it? Assuming am just experimenting on a few things here and there and would want to run the code so many times...is there a way it can just pop up in its window like when using the code ```plt.show()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `import webbrowser` and open the saved html file in your browser.

```
import folium
import webbrowser

m = folium.Map(location=[40.0150, -105.2705])
m.save("map.html")
# Display the map
webbrowser.open("map.html")
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the best alternative, building on the answer by @Yabberth

Answer (score 0):

Just like yabberth said save the map as `map.html` after saving html call the system command like `os.system('map.html')`